# How to do work with an object which is stored in an arraylist?

Tags: arraylist

Suppose I want to print the value of votes earnd by a candidate object which is stored in an arraylist.

Here, 'votes' is an int variable associated with candidate object.

Answer (score 0):

In psuedocode terms:

```
foreach (candidate in candidateList) {
  print(candidate.votes)
}
```

this would iterate through a list of candidates held in some type of enumerable (i.e arraylist) and print them to a standard output for whatever language you're using.